# Prove that the area enclosed by a convex closed regular simple plane curve is lower or equal to width times diameter

Tags: differential-geometry, plane-curves, plane-geometry

I'm try to proof that the area of a convex closed regular simple plane curve is lower or equal to width times the diameter ($A \leq w D$). Intuitively, it's clear that $A \leq w D$, because the convex closed regular simple plane curve can be enclosed by a rectangle with base length $D$ and height length $w$ as shown in the figure below

[image: Convex closed plane curve in black and rectangle which encloses the curve]

I would like to know how can I proof that $A \leq w D$. I tried to proof by Isoperimetric Inequality, but I just prove with this that $A \leq L D$ as shown in my attempt below.

> $\textbf{My attempt:}$
>
> The curve is a Jordan's Curve, then we can use the Isoperimetric Inequality:
>
> $$4 \pi A \leq L^2,$$
>
> where $A$ is the area enclosed by the curve and $L$ is the length of the curve
>
> Because the diameter is the maximum of width of a curve ($L \leq D$), we have that
>
> $$L^2 \leq LD,$$
>
> then
>
> $$A \leq \frac{L^2}{4 \pi} \leq \frac{LD}{4 \pi} \leq LD$$

Thanks in advance!

$\textbf{EDIT:}$

> I saw two definitions of width, so I'll put both definitions.
>
> $\textbf{First definition of width (in terms of support function)}$: the width of a convex curve $\alpha$ in the direction $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ is given by $w(\theta) = \varrho(\theta) + \varrho(\theta + \pi)$, where $\theta$ is the angle oriented positively between the normal unit vector of the curve and $e_1$ and $\varrho$ is the support function of the curve.
>
> For the second definition of width that I see, there are some illustrations motivating the definition:

[image: $\textit{larg}_v(\alpha)$ is the width of the curve $\alpha$ in the direction $v$]

> $\textbf{Second definition of width}$: for each $v \in \mathbb{S^1}$, consider the function $h$ defined by
>
> $$h(v) := \max_{a \leq s \leq b}\langle \alpha(s), v \rangle$$
>
> In terms of $h$, we write the width of $\alpha$ in direction $v$ as
>
> $$\textit{larg}_v(\alpha) := h(v) + h(-v)$$
>
> The diameter of a curve is the maximum distance between two points on trace of the curve $\alpha$.
>
> I stated earlier that "the diameter is the maximum of width of a curve" because was proved in the book where I saw the second definition of width the following proposition:
>
> $\textbf{Proposition}$: For every regular and closed curve $\alpha: [a,b] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, the diameter $D$ of $\alpha$ is given by
>
> $$D = \max_{v \in \mathbb{S}^1} \textit{larg}_v(\alpha)$$

Comment: What is the definition of width here? I only know it in the context of curves of constant width (breadth). In that context, assuming the curve is differentiable, it gives you the diameter. Do you want to take the *diameter* to be the maximum distance between parallel tangent lines and the *width* to be the minimum distance between parallel tangent lines?

Comment: @TedShifrin, I edited my post and put the definitions.

Comment: I still don't see a definition of width. You gave me width in a given direction. As I said before, the diameter is the maximum of such a width. What's the $w$ in the proposition you want to prove?

Comment: @TedShifrin, $w$ is the width of the curve. I confess that I don't understand what exactly width is. It looks like for me that width would be like "the minimum distance" between two parallel tangent lines of the curve $\alpha$, I searched many material to understand this definition, but I found just two books that contains these two definitions. Maybe, it's more useful I say what led me to try prove this: I'm trying read the article "The heat equation shrinking convex plane curves"  by Hamilton and Gage and, when they proved the Geometric Estimate, they state in the middle of proof that

Comment: "the area is bounded by the width times the diameter", then I'm trying to understand why it's true.

Comment: George, I found the definition of width confirming our conclusions (minimum distance between parallel tangents) in Santaló's Integral Geometry book. He also gives the inequality that $wD\le 2A$ but explicitly does not give $A\le wD$. Weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $K$ be the convex body bounded by the given curve. It is clear $K$ has same diameter $D$ as its boundary.

For any $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$, let $w(\theta)$ be the width of the shadow if you project $K$ orthogonally to a line with tangent pointing in direction of $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$. Define the "minimum width" of the curve as

$$w_{min} \stackrel{def}{=} \min\big\{\; w(\theta) : \theta \in \mathbb{R} \;\big\}$$

WOLOG, consider the case $w_{min}$ is achieved at $\theta = 0$. i.e
The projection is most narrow when the line to project is along the $x$-axis.
Translate $K$ so that it is sandwiched between the line $x = 0$ and the line $x = w_{min}$. For each $x \in [0,w_{min}]$, let $h(x)$ be the length of the line segment $\{ (x,y ) : (x,y) \in K \}$. Since any such line segment is a subset of $K$, we have $h(x) \le D$. "Summing" contribution from all these line segments, we obtain:

$$\verb/Area/(K) = \int_0^{w_{min}} h(x) dx \le \int_0^{w_{min}} D dx = w_{min} D$$

Comment: You don't mean $y\in K$. :) But thanks for giving the right argument.

Comment: @TedShifrin oops, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @achillehui, can you show with an illustration what is the $w$ according your definition of width? I can't see that your definition of width is the distance between two tangent parallel lines. If possible, can you recommend me any introductory textbook in Convex Geometry? I never study Convex Geometry and try understand some definitions involving convex sets is being hard to me without many references in the subject. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @George This definition of width is equivalent to the definition using support function. It is just presented in a slightly more geometric manner. In general, I use Luis Santaló's book "Integral Geometry and Geometric Probability" as reference of this sort of stuff.

Comment: @achillehui, I understood, thanks a lot!